# Laravel get with polymorphic relationship after save()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have something like that:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->name = "lorem"
//some polymorphic relationship (hasOne)
$order->user()->save(new User());
return $order;
```

the problem is that I want to get order returned with `user`. I tried something like that and it worked:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->name = "lorem"
//some polymorphic relationship (hasOne)
$order->user()->save(new User());
$order->user;
return $order;
```

But I feel that I am doing something wrong and there should be better way to achieve the same result, so how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Eloquent has 2 methods, load and with, you may choose the ideal one for you (in this case load).

You may use the following code:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->name = "lorem"
//some polymorphic relationship (hasOne)
$order->user()->save(new User());

return $order->load('user');
```